# General approach when needing to calculate values between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the following table :

```
Id    Timestamp    AssignedTo
1     2012-01-01   User1
2     2012-01-02   User2
3     2012-01-10   User3
4     2012-01-15   User1
```

what would be the **general approach** in MS SQL Server to calculating how many days/hours/minutes the entity was assigned to a specific user?

As a developer (with basic SQL knowledge), I've always opted for Functions or Stored procedures when doing these kind of queries (these kind = queries including results based on the difference between two rows in a set).

In this example, I'd have a cursor iterating over the items, keeping the previous one in a variable, and then calculating the difference. However, I've been told that this is a serious performance concern, especially on large sets.

EDIT: Sample results

```
User    TotalTime
User1   23d
User2   8d
User3   5d
```

i.e. the total time that an item was assigned to a specific user. User1's TotalTime is 23 days because it has been assigned to him since 2012-01-15 (and it's 2012-02-06 now), along with the first day it was assigned to him.

Comment: Depending on the database, you could use advanced SQL features, so what database is this? Besides, can you provide some example output? I'm not sure what result you'd expect...

Comment: Added sample data, and MSSQL DBMS.

Comment: Too bad it's MSSQL/SQL Server, so you cannot use `ROWS 1 PRECEDING` and similar window function constructs. But check out this question here, it'll contain some answers to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver

Comment: So why is `User2`'s TotalTime = 8d?

Comment: @El because it was assigned to `User2` on these days: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, which is eight days

Comment: @AakashM Right! Sorry for being daft :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example I'd use a subquery within the select statement to get the end date for each row, then use this end date to get the time assigned to a specific user. The below is SQL Server syntax but the same principal can be applied whatever the RDBMS.

```
SELECT  AssignedTo, 
        SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, TimeStamp, ISNULL(EndDate, GETDATE()))) [Days]
FROM    (   SELECT  ID,
                    [TimeStamp],
                    AssignedTo,
                    (   SELECT  MIN(TimeStamp)
                        FROM    [YOURTABLE] b
                        WHERE   b.TimeStamp > a.TimeStamp
                    ) [EndDate]
            FROM    [YOURTABLE] a
        )  a
GROUP BY AssignedTo
```

Comment: Even though I was looking for a general approach, this answer lead me to it... a practical example of what I believe is called set theory.